# Color Spectrum of Heated Metal

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, temperature, material-science, metals

I have seen a few questions and answers according this subject.
What troubles me, is that I saw somewhere that there is a difference between oxidation colors and  incandescent colors when heating metal. I would like to understand the difference and what happens when.

Answer (score 3):

Oxidation colours are due to a thin oxide layer on the surface, [causing light interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference) that generates the colour. The colour depends on the layer thickness and index of refraction.

[Flame colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_test) are due to atoms being swept up in a hot flame and emitting their emission spectrum. The colours are determined by the electron structure of the atoms.

Finally, there is the [blackbody colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) that comes from matter emitting light when it is hot enough. Here the colour is a broad spectrum due to photons being emitted as a maximum entropy distribution.

So the different colours you see are due to three very different processes and do not have to match. Which one dominates depends on circumstances: at low temperature you mostly notice the surface film color, in flames the flame colour may be vivid if there is not much other light, and for high temperature blackbody radiation matters.

Comment: What considers 'low' or 'high'? Why doesn't the light appear during simple heating of home-oven?

Comment: I can see some bright red blackbody radiation from the heating coils in my home oven, and I think they are maybe 700 C. You can maybe see some dark red at 500 C. Meanwhile boron gives cool water-alcohol flames a green colour at a much lower temperature.